# CSS extra space issue in IE9

Tags: css

My site is cross-browser compatible but in IE9 it is showing the extra space between navigation and content part.

You can see the issue [here](http://gotskinswholesales.com/index.php?main_page=page&id=16).

How can I fix it?

Comment: your page has the extra space in Chrome too..

Comment: The extra space is visible in FF too. Also, your code is kinda.. messy... and scattered, hard to read.

Comment: `<div id="navBreadCrumb" style="margin-top: 190px;"></div>` - remove that `margin-top`. It's that extra space

Comment: there is no id navBreadCrumb ?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting lots of whitespace because you are using position:relative and then using clear="all" tags after. This is pushing all of your content down below that. Try using absolute positioning (position:absolute;) instead and make the parent container position:relative;

I think you've got a lot more to worry about here though. Your coding is a big mess and it makes it extremely difficult to pinpoint the error(although I think that is it). I recommend taking all your CSS and putting it in a separate style.css stylesheet and consider doing the same for javascript.

Also you have **161 errors** in your script as well as **194 warnings**. (see for yourself at http://validator.w3.org/). These errors are going to cause all sorts of problems for you and make it extremely hard to get everything to layout as you like (also google will punish your search engine results). I know there are a lot of errors but it won't be so bad to go through and fix them all as most are duplicates. Also you will learn all sorts of new things :) Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

It's the `div` with `id="navBreadCrumb"` that causes the space, as it has a top margin of `190px`. The margin collapses with the outer element and pushes the `div` with `id="new_main"` down. Then you are using relative positioning to make the content display `90px` furter up.

If you remove the margin and the relative positioning, you get rid of `100px` of blank space.